Why do we need a religion like Islam when reality suggests otherwise?
Islam, as a religion, often appears not to provide concrete solutions to real-world problems. Instead, it tends to offer alternative explanations or attributes everything to Allah without an apparent practical basis. Here are a few examples:
Example #1: Islam advises that when faced with difficulties, one should pray to Allah, remain patient, be resilient, and continue putting in effort—promising that Allah will ultimately grant success. However, it seems that having patience, staying strong, and continuing efforts alone will lead to success, regardless of invoking Allah. This raises the question: why involve a theological concept when tangible action already holds the potential to resolve the issue?
Example #2: Currently, Israel is mercilessly slaughtering Palestinians in large numbers. Islam doesn’t seem to provide an adequate explanation for why this is happening or why Palestinians are being persecuted without any apparent wrongdoing. The practical cause is Zionism, which drives this aggression. Islam, as a religion, appears powerless to counter Zionism, especially since Zionists wield significant control over money and power.
Example #3: Islam advocates for the implementation of Sharia to uphold the rule of law. However, in a world dominated by Western hegemony, implementing Sharia is practically impossible unless the entire global order changes, which seems highly unlikely. Furthermore, nations that have well-established rules of law are often not Muslim-majority countries.
Example #4: Islam does not promote the concept of nationalism or states. Yet, under current global realities shaped by Western influence and institutions like the United Nations, one cannot simply disregard the concepts of nationalism and the state.
Given these examples, the question arises: why do we need a religion like Islam when reality suggests otherwise?

I thought about the first point. Like Islam  says be humble but doesn't really tell how. "Be humble for the sake of God" but doesn't really tell what actions or thought process needed to be inrernalized to become an humble being.

@Hardshell, regarding your query, ask a question and give me the link. Being humble has some traits. I will write an answer.

"Why do we need a religion like Islam?" You might as well ask the same question of any worldly authority or government; "Why do we need X legal system" or "Why do we need Y as a leader". If you follow a worldly leader, they may promise worldly rewards. Some of them may actually follow through on those promises. That is your answer.
If you read the Qur'an, Allah has made a number of promises to the believers; most of them are for rewards in the afterlife so it's no surprise that you don't see them reflected in this world:

And this worldly life is not but diversion and amusement. And indeed, the home of the Hereafter - that is the [eternal] life, if only they knew.
— Al-`Ankabut 64

Nowhere does He promise that He would withhold is bounty from disbelievers and only give them to Muslims. Or that we'd get everything you want and never be tested in it, that we could avoid death, whether it is in war or peace, that everything would be easy to implement while also accommodating non-Muslim ideals.
And ultimately, if you are not interested in any of the rewards that Allah has actually promised to the Muslims, to the believers, and are not worried about any of the punishments that He has promised on those who reject him, then you can say you have no need for this religion.
But that's missing the point entirely.
Whether or not Allah exists isn't based on religion; Islam teaches that He doesn't need us to believe in him, He exists regardless. His Grace applies to all mankind, he gives favor and takes it away as He pleases, believers and disbelievers all, and as the Lord of all creation it is his prerogative to do so.

…Had Allah willed, He would have made you one nation, but to test you in what He has given you; so race to [all that is] good…
— Al-Ma'idah 48

Firaun wasn't brought low because of religion, He was defeated because Allah decreed so. So can be said for any other great power, whether they believe in Allah or not. Even during the time of the prophet, when Muslims were fighting against their enemies, those enemies were defeated thanks to Allah:

And you did not kill them, but it was Allah who killed them. And you threw not, when you threw, but it was Allah who threw that He might test the believers with a good test. Indeed, Allah is Hearing and Knowing.
— Al-'Anfal 17

The whole point of this worldly life is to test people, and believing in Allah is part of that test. But so is humility; while we may choose to stay strong and continually strive to better ourselves, whether we succeed or not is not up to us. In the face of the vast universe, we are all weak and powerless: You don't need faith to realize this, but it definitely helps us recognize and accept it.
Similarly when you look at the world around you and see terrible things happening, many people believe that they through effort, alone or with others, can change that. This is an arrogant belief since no amount of effort can guarantee any particular outcome. Islam teaches that we are judged based on the decisions we make, but not on the outcomes which are outside of our control. We are rewarded for trying, not necessarily for succeeding.
Getting back to the core of your question, "Why do we need a religion like Islam", the answer is you really don't. We don't need "a religion", we need Allah, and Allah has given us this religion. Those who believe in Allah and know that He is Good, know that what He has given us is Good, and follow His laws and His guidance because it is our benefit to do so, even if we don't fully understand how.
But just following a bunch of arbitrary rules alone is meaningless; even the hypocrites could do that. Ultimately what matters is belief in Allah, trust in Allah, and having faith that Allah's promise is true.

Conveniently ignored all the supplied examples like this YouTube videos: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/84900/58163.

@user366312 That is not a youtube video, and even if it was I doubt it would have any relevance to my answer.

This is an arrogant belief since no amount of effort can guarantee any particular outcome. --- this could happen regardless even if we depend on Allah.

That is not a youtube video, --- I listed some video links in that post.

@user366312 If it was relevant to the question it should've been included in the question. Otherwise, stop wasting my time, I am not interested in an argument, nor am I interested in watching any videos.

Otherwise, stop wasting my time, I am not interested in an argument. --- there is no arguing with you. Your answer doesn't answer the original question. This is just beating around the bushes.
